# How to make an assertion to find xpath?

Tags: python, selenium

Bear with me, I am very new to this. I am writing in Python using `Selenium Webdriver`.

I have a test written out and I want to make an `assertion` to find is a `class` is present. I have tried multiple ways to go about to do this however i feel as though it is not working correctly.

I have attached a photo of the code I am looking at (the highlighted line) and this is what I have so far. This fires which is a pop up to notify a success the form was submitted.

```
self.assertTrue(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="message-center"]/div'))
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you finding the div above it and then dropping down to that div vs just going straight to that div using the class attribute?  If you are asserting that the class exists, I would prolly go straight to the div with the class in it.

Comment: //div[@class='alert alert-success show'] or //div[contains(@class, 'alert-success')] would be the xpath I would use.  I dunno if this helps you in your assert or not though.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would take advantage of the .find_elements method. It will return an empty list if no such elements are found.

```
self.assertTrue(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="message-center"]/div').count() > 0);
```